# Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0

I detached app server from config database using configuration wizard then I am running a configuration wizard to re attach it. It is throwing an below error. When I go and looked services on the same server "Windows SharePoint Services Web Application" is not showing at all and everything else working.

Please tell me how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say you've detached the Central Admin server, and the remaining server(s) in the farm don't have a central admin instance. You might need to provision Central Admin onto one of the existing servers before rejoining this one.

there's a psconfig.exe command. run:

psconfig.exe -help adminvs

on a member server in the farm to see how it works. Provisioning a new CA instance inside the farm should be the way to go.

psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 12345

I'd hope this would work. But I might be wrong.